# MySQL Spatial Queries not working when migrated from MySQL 5.7.26 to MySQL 8.0.23

Tags: mysql, gis, geospatial, spatial

I am no MySQL expert so no doubt I have overlooked something simple.

I have a MySQL DB (V 5.7.26) and if I run the following query (as an example) on one of my tables I get a result of 39 which is what I expect:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `entities` 
WHERE
ST_CONTAINS(
    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-0.4120 51.6009, -0.4120 51.3467, 0.1533  51.3467, 0.1533  51.6009, -0.4120 51.6009))', 4326),
    gloc
) = 1;
```

I created the same DB in MySQL V 8.0.23 and did so by exporting table definitions and recreating them by running the queries in the new DB, so as far as I can tell tables definitions etc are identical.

I imported the same data into the new DB and I know the data is correct, for example if I pull a record by another criteria(selecting by record id for example) I can display the record on a map (leaflet) and it is in the correct location.

However if I run the same query as above in my new DB it returns a result of 0.

If I leave out the SRID of 4326 then I get an error (which I would expect) of

```
/* SQL Error (3033): Binary geometry function st_contains given two geometries of different srids: 0 and 4326, which should have been identical. */
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 1 query: 0.000 sec. */
```

So I don't think its an SRID issue.

gloc is defined as type 'geometry', NULL values are allowed though none exist. However if I disallow NULL values and then add a spatial index to gloc column the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would check lat:lon order. MySql 8 follows lat:lon order for 4326 as defined by CRS. Assuming your data is in England, rather than Indian ocean, you should swap coordinate order. Also check other data for same issue.

See also
https://mysqlserverteam.com/axis-order-in-spatial-reference-systems/